# Get a vlookup of a cell after split in Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

I have an incident Google form where there might be an input with ID numbers separated by . or / that have the same incident. I need in Google sheet to lookup the value of the ID numbers associated with the same incident and allocate it the same incident information.

I was able to split and jointext and transpose but I cannot get the incident information for each, and I need it to expand when new entries come in so an arrayformula is a must I think.

Here is what it looks like.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JILaU.png)

Here is what I was able to do with the formula

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(".", 1, C2:C), "."))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQOzf.png)

And here is what I need as output.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sq0gy.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=query(arrayformula(split(arrayformula(FLATTEN(split(A2:A4,".")&"|"&B2:B4)),"|")),"select * where Col2 is not null")
```

[image]

Comment: Thx for your feedback, upvote and close the topic, see you soon for other tips

Comment: Somehow, it is treating the values as strings not numbers and so the vlookup  I am using to look up  student information is not finding its ID number. I tried formatting it but it is not working.

Comment: in my example, I retrieve numbers ... hope this will help you : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nszZ-JdUpCNXD0PqVqcVr3dmssG4jFtQsYxQe8PpBJk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It might be because I changed the separator to "/" instead of ".". It worked with the latter but not the former.

Comment: I am amazed ... wat is text for you and what is number ? can you share a sort spreadsheet ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Here is an example The output in column C is not 
 a number value. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zNZYecCB3nD4E9VWF4lUA8bXpcI-qEKpshp35ZEA3yo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Transform the parameter to a text with `to_text` as in the spreadsheet.