# mapping vlookup for each element of splitted list in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, apply, vlookup

This question is also answered here:
[Get a vlookup of a cell after split in Google sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69230297/get-a-vlookup-of-a-cell-after-split-in-google-sheet)

but not marked as corrected answer, and cannot make it work.

**Goal** : I want to apply a vlookup function to a split function, so that I can search for corresponding values (found by the vlookup) for each token obtained from a string.

Consider this sheets:

// Sheet 'veggies'

| A |
| --- |
| apple, pine, tree |
| pine |

// Sheet 'themes':

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple | 8 | theme1,theme2 |
| tree | 3 | theme2 |
| pine | 1 | theme1,theme3 |

I want to:

1. split cells of column A of 'veggies' by commas, so to have tokens
2. vlookup for the C column in 'themes' sheet, by using the index of tokens, for all of them

As approach I tried to first retrieve the frequences of tokens in column B, sheet 'themes', and cannot understand what my formula is doing:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA( VLOOKUP( split(A2;",");'themes'!A$2:D;2;FALSE))
```

This formula only get the frequency from column be for the *first* token, while for others will only report `N/A` saying could not find a value, but it is clearly there.

Any help?
Am I on the right track ?

P.s. if one would like to offer use of `query` , like in the other SO answer, please help me to break down what it does.

Comment: you want it reported in a single cell? so the VLOOKUP for A2 should return....

`theme1, theme 2, theme 2, theme 1, theme 3` ? If not, what should it return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ARRAYFORMULA( VLOOKUP( split(A2;",");'themes'!A$2:D;2;FALSE))

Your formula works. But when splitting by comma `,` there's a extra space left over in all the elements from the second element. So, when
`apple, pine, tree` is splitted, it becomes `apple`, `pine`, `tree`(note the extra space prefix). To fix, you can simply add a space to the split as well:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA( VLOOKUP( split(A2;", ");'themes'!A$2:D;2;FALSE))
```

Comment: I noticed it, but actually I have data as "apple juice" in A2, and with split(A2;", ") it will break the string as "apple", "juice" as well. cannot figure out why. So I am trying smtg more convoluted with transpose etc. but could not fixed it yet:/

you can imagine that both Columns As and Cs have composed token, I mean data could be as "this is theme 1; this is theme 2" referring to token "apple juice" ..

Comment: @user305883 Split will split by each character in the delimiter argument.

Comment: you mean that `", "` will split at both `","` AND `" "` ?
This is unexpected behaviour, I was thinking split will be only at `", "` sequence. So, a `"word1,word2"` or `"word1 word2"` would not be split, but  only `"word1, wordy word2"` > `word1`, `wordy word2`.

Is there any other solution ?
I ended up using a combination of `unique(trim(flatten(`  or  `regexreplace( TEXT ;"^ ,";"")` but that is convoluted...

Comment: @user305883 That is right. It'll split by both the space and the comma. There's a third argument to `split()`: `split_by_each`, which by default is true. You can turn it off: `=split(text;", ",false)` will split if all the sequence of characters is in the right order.

Comment: darn, why did I not read the documentation ... ? sometimes pausing and getting back with more serene mindset is better than perseverance.. ahah - thanks @TheMaster

Answer (score 0):

this should work if you want the results in one cell.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(", ";TRUE;IFERROR(VLOOKUP(SPLIT(A2;", ";0);themes!A:C,2,0))))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use this formual**

```
=ArrayFormula(LAMBDA(v,
 IF(v="",,{v,SPLIT(VLOOKUP(v,themes!A2:C,3,0), ", ",1)}))
 (FLATTEN(IF(A2:A="",,SPLIT(A2:A, ", ", 1)))))
```

[image]