# Using cyclical formulas to reduce lag in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

At work we have a giant google sheet (right now about 7 thousand rows) where we track documents

Lately this sheet started to slow down considerably (5-10 second delay before formulas are calculated)

We have very few formulas. Main one is this - one of our workers types contract id in the first column (A3) and sheet looks up relevant date in another sheet sheet and adds it to other columns (B3). In my example it only adds company name

Im thinking that main problem is that google sheets re-calculates everything (including already filled rows) every time something changes on the sheet. So my question is this - can i use cyclical formulas to make it so formulas are calculated only once?

Our current formulas are similar to this:

```
=IF(A3 <> "";INDEX('Tech data'!$B$1:$B$22;(MATCH(A3;'Tech data'!$A$1:$A$22; 0))); "")
```

[Adding link to demonstration sheet to better show formulas](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1spSYDnHoV2f9gmw4votjuXJVGKc1Ym3prlYYMM6LfaA/edit?usp=sharing)

**My attempted solution:**

I made this formula to try and force Google sheets to calculate it only once:

```
=IF(A3<>""; IF(B3 <> ""; B3; INDEX('Tech data'!$B$1:$B$22; MATCH(A3; 'Tech data'!$A$1:$A$22; 0)));"")
```

Basically idea is -

1. If nothing is entered in Company ID column - then return empty space.
2. Else check if cell with this formula (B3) is NOT empty - then make b3 = b3
3. Else if b3 is EMPTY - then use index+match formula to get company name

I set google sheets to allow cyclical formulas and set it to only calculate it once

My idea is that should make already calculated cells "locked" - google will know that this cyclical cell was alread calculated once, so it shouldnt calculate it again

I tried replacing all formulas, but havent noticed big improvement (but this table is very temperamental - sometimes it works flawlessly, sometime it lags)

I already used other simple ways i know to make google sheet work faster - removed all unused empty cells, got rid of almost all conditional formatting, made sure that index+match is only running if A cell is not empty. I heard that looking up data on another sheet can also slow things down, but i havent tried to fix that yet. Might just add all relevant data as an array to some hidden columns and use THAT data for clculations

Comment: We obviously can't 'see' the lagging you're seeing as your demo sheet is quite small, however I would think based on the demo sheet that you probably have a very large number of copy-pasted formulas which could probably be substituted by a small number of array formulas. Also, XLOOKUPs can replace INDEX/MATCH (and are easier to understand), and evaluating large numbers of cells for <>"" is probably not great; it would be more efficient to find the last filled cell in the column and limit the array to that range.

Comment: Yes, Arrayformula was recommended to me, so i will try to use that. I used index+Match instead of vlookup or xlookup because i was always taught its better (can do 3 dimensional ranges, return ata from any row/column regardles of where you search and so on)

Comment: 1) How many rows in "Main Sheet"? if you use a formula with an argument `A3:A` then it will calculate for **every** row regardless of which cell/rows are populated. 2) `We have very few formulas` I wouldn't think that _this_ formula should have a _big_ effect on performance (unless perhaps there are 1,000 rows on "Main Sheet"). I agree with the sentiment expressed by @TheGodofBiscuits - to be getting a significant lag you must have other formulas running, and it's impossible to really assist on that score without seeing the actual data/formulas.

Comment: Right now there are 7340 rows (and we only keep rows that we need - there are only ~50 empty rows under the filled ones) with very similar formula: take the value in the first column, search it in the database of 1300 rows, and return a value

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula in Cell A2 on Main sheet:

`=map(A2:A;lambda(v; IF(v="";;VLOOKUP(v;'Tech data'!A1:B;2;0))))`

(configured for using `;` as argument separators)

adapted from [mapping vlookup for each element of splitted list in google sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73855407/1330560)

**Note:** So far as performance is concerned, reduce the number of rows on "Main Sheet" to a minimum, since the formula calculates values for **every** cell in the column.

---

**SAMPLE**

[image: snapshot]